# SetupSet() is obsolete. In place of what?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mocking, moq

Let's say I want to use Moq to create a callback on a setter to store the set property in my own field for later use.  (Contrived example - but it gets to the point of the question.)  I could do something like this:

```
myMock.SetupSet(x => x.MyProperty).Callback(value => myLocalVariable = value);
```

And that works just fine.  However, SetupSet is obsolete according to Intellisense.  But it doesn't say what should be used as an alternative.  I know that moq provides SetupProperty which will autowire the property with a backing field.  But that is not what I'm looking for.  I want to capture the set value into my own variable.  How should I do this using non-obsolete methods?

Answer (score 121, accepted):

I am using Moq version 3.0.204.1 and `SetupSet` does is not marked as obsolete for me. However, there are a couple of `SetupSet` overloads located in `MockLegacyExtensions`. You can avoid using those and use `SetupSet` that is defined on the `Mock` class.

The difference is subtle and you need to use `Action<T>` as `SetupSet` parameter, as opposed to `Func<T, TProperty>`.

The call below will invoke the non-deprecated overload:

```
myMock.SetupSet(p => p.MyProperty = It.IsAny<string>()).Callback<string>(value => myLocalVariable = value);
```

The trick is to use `It.IsAny<string>`, which will intercept a setter call with any value.

Comment: It's a shame that you need to specify the generic argument for `Callback<>`

Comment: @RobSiklos What shame? In the [QuickStart](https://code.google.com/p/moq/wiki/QuickStart) it called _alternate equivalent generic method syntax_

Comment: @RobSiklos You can write `Callback((string value) => myLocalVariable = value)`

Comment: If you want to "do nothing" :                myMock.SetupSet(p => p.MyIntProperty = It.IsAny<int>())
            .Callback<int>(value => _ = value /* do nothing */);